# Why does the fio package use Python2.7?

Tags: 20.04

I am using fio package with version 3.16.1, and it requires Python2.7, I tried removing Python2.7 and fio still works.

So I'm wondering when does fio use Python2.7 and is it possible to remove it ?

Or is it possible to force it to use with Python3?

https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/fio_3.16-1_amd64.deb.html

Comment: [`man fio`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/fio.1.html) says: "Also included with fio is a Python script fio_jsonplus_clat2csv that  takes  json+  output and generates CSV-formatted latency data suitable for plotting." That's _probably_ what it is, but I'm too lazy to look at the actual package to see if there's anything else.

Comment: Thanks sir, but I'm having a concern that : Or is it possible to force it to use with Python3 ?  because there are some vunerability with Python2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible, since [`fio` for Jammy](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/fio) uses Python 3.

So the answer to *"Why is it that..."*, is probably *"The developers transitioned the `fio` package to Python 3 somewhere between Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04"*.

So could you make a more recent version for Focal? Probably yes, if you're willing to do the work yourself. So you basically have 3 options:

1. Stay on Ubuntu 20.04 and `fio` w. Python 2
2. Modify/update the `fio` source and recompile it for Ubuntu 20.04
3. Upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 (where the work has been done for you)

As @Muru states, it's probably some of the helper scripts that use Python, and you said yourself that the binary works, even though you removed Python 2.

###### Reflections on Python 2 vulnerabilities

When you state *"there are some vulnerability in Python 2..."*, it seems you're not really considering the vulnerabilities and how they come into play.

I can only assume you're referencing [CVE-2021-4189](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2021-4189) and [CVE-2022-0391](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2022-0391), which you asked about previously. Please consider what they actually are: CVE-2021-4189 is about the FTP module, and CVE-2022-0391 is about URL parsing.

So you need to consider: Do you really have any attack surfaces that expose these vulnerabilities in a way where it poses a risk? You could start by checking the source code of the Python scripts included with `fio`:

For [`fio_jsonplus_clat2csv`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/fio/-/blob/master/tools/fio_jsonplus_clat2csv) line 81-87 imports modules:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import json
import argparse
import itertools
import six
```

And [`fiologparser.py`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/fio/-/blob/master/tools/fiologparser.py) line 17-21 imports modules:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function
import argparse
import math
from functools import reduce
```

Since none of them use `ftplib` or `urllib.parse` modules, then the vulnerabilities don't even come into play. So there isn't any *known* issue here at all, even if you're using Python 2.